# How to create Qt GUI application from dll called by win32 console application?

Tags: qt, winapi, user-interface, mfc

(I am not native English so Sorry if I make any grammar mistake)

I am new to Qt, started 2 days ago, and had only few experiences of WINAPI and MFC.
I am thinking of...

First, creating Qt GUI application from its dll
Second, my static library file(*.lib) will call this dll file using QLibrary.
Lastly, my console application will have its lib and its header file, and dll to create Qt GUI Application.

and my console application does not have .pro file, just created on visual studio and has only .vcproj and .sln file.

Here is the source code:
http://cfile239.uf.daum.net/attach/037B654151C4FF8D2D0EB7

I copied dll, lib and its header file into its win32 console application.
and when I compile console, I get this error message.

**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QApplication': No such file or directory**

I know it is absolutely right. (cuz my lib uses QLibrary and its lib and header file is included in win32 console application..)

well, actually I do not want to have .pro file including QApplication class into my console application to fix this problem.

Is there any possible way to fix it while avoiding having .pro file?
or should I create .pro and set it to have QT library?

Thank you for reading it. :D

Comment: http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/p/qt.html HTH use qmake to create .pro hope you have qt add in for visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indicate your compiler Qt's path.
If you use vs,choose tools->option->project and solutions,VC++ Directories,set your Qt header files path,lib path,bin path, and set Qt's bin path to environment variable PATH.
In your static library project, try this:

create.h

```
#pragma once
void createQt(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

create.cpp

```
#include<QtGui/QWidget>
#include<QtGui/QApplication>
#include "create.h"
#pragma  comment(lib,"qtguid4.lib")
void createQt(int argc, char* argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc,argv);

QWidget w;
w.show();
app.exec();
};
```

in you console program:

.cpp file:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "create.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"CreaeQt.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

createQt(argc,argv);

return 0;
}
```